# Function to return list of strings starting with a character

Tags: c#

I want to write a function for taking a list of strings and a character, that returns a list of just those strings that start with that character.

```
public List<string> Sort(List<string> MyList, char MyChar)
{
  //This is the format I want
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want? Because the function name is called Sort.

Comment: HA! Not helping you get a job. Should earn it sir...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work for what you described:

```
public List<string> Sort(List<string> theList, char theChar)
{
    List<string> output = new List<string>();

    foreach(string s in theList)
    {
        if (s.StartsWith(theChar.ToString()))
        {
            output.Add(s);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Don't want to sound harsh, but if you cant implement this code yourself, you are under qualified for the job.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested, here's one way to go about it using LINQ:

```
public List<string> Sort(List<string> list, char character)
{
    return  list.Where(s => s.StartsWith(character.ToString())).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is code

let a list of String is:

```
 List<string> listOfString = new List<string>();
        listOfString.Add("Allah");
        listOfString.Add("Mohammad(SAW)");
        listOfString.Add("Islam");
```

here function which return List..

```
public List<string> GetListOFStrinStartWithAChar(List<string> stringList, char ch)
    {
        List<string> temp = (from s in stringList where s.StartsWith(ch.ToString()) select s).ToList<string>();
        return temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in linq

```
var list = new List<string>() {"Apple", "Alice", "Bob", "Candy"};
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(i => i.StartsWith("C"));
```

So you can just package it as a function

```
// Sort the list descending by start with char
public static List<string> Sort(List<string> MyList, char MyChar)
{
    return MyList
        .OrderByDescending(i => i.StartsWith(MyChar.ToString()))
        .ToList();
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vZl2aH)